# Adding a function to page load event from pre render event

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working in a asp.net project(ASP.NET 4.0,c#,WebForms).

I need to add a function to the Page Load event based on some conditions in Page Prerender event.How can i achieve this.

I tried the following code,

```
Page_Load += new EventHandler(delegate(object sender, EventArgs e) { ShowForm(); });
```

But it doesn't work.Can someone provide some insight on this?

Answer (score 2):

You can't, in the pre-render event you're too late, the Load event has already happened!

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Not possible - `Page_Load` event happens [before](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) `Page_Prerender` event.

I also suspect that perhaps you are mixing between server side events and client side events - you may want to perform some logic when page gets loaded at the client side (which is different than `page_load` event - which happens on the server side).

Perhaps you can try to explain what exactly you want to achieve by the code that you have sighted and you may get better answers that would solve your actual problem.